# Python unicode string rejected by psycopg

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode, psycopg2

I've received a unicode string from the wild that causes some of our psycopg2 statements to fail.

I have reduced the problem down to a SSCE:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cur = conn.cursor()
x = u'\ud837'
cur.execute("SELECT %s", (x,))
print cur.fetchone()
```

Running this gives the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../run.py", line 65, in <module>
    cur.execute("SELECT %s AS test", (x,))
psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xed 0xa0 0xb7
```

Based on some of the comments, it has become clear that this particular character is one half of a surrogate pair, making it invalid to live on its own.

Specifically then, I am looking for a mechanism to detect when a string contains an incomplete surrogate pair in Python 2.

One such method I have found that leads to an exception is trying `x.encode('utf16').decode('utf16')`, however, since I don't totally understand the risks associated, I would be somewhat concerned here.

Edit: Reduced SSCE string to single character causing the problem, added information based on comments.

Comment: The character represents [one half of a surrogate pair](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d837/index.htm) and doesn't represent a code point of its own.  Presumably you obtained it through an API that split a UTF-16-encoded string without paying attention to character boundaries.

Comment: @user4815162342 so how can I detect whether a given string in python contains any such incomplete surrogate pairs?

Comment: Just curious, has my answer helped with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `u'\ud837'` consists of a lone member of a [surrogate pair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5903080/1600898), two physical characters that appear in sequence to form a logical character. As such, it does not define a Unicode code point - instead, it is an implementation detail of the UTF-16 encoding which uses it to pack the full code point range into 16-bit code units. Python 3 correctly rejects attempts to encode lone surrogates in any byte encoding, including the UTF-* variants.

The string probably originated from a system that internally uses UTF-16 (such as Java, C#, Windows, or Python 2 built with 16-bit `Py_UNICODE`) that naively shortened the string without taking care of surrogates.

Taking the regex from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18674109/1600898), it should be possible to efficiently detect such strings using code such as:

```
import re

lone = re.compile(
    ur'''(?x)            # verbose expression (allows comments)
    (                    # begin group
    [\ud800-\udbff]      #   match leading surrogate
    (?![\udc00-\udfff])  #   but only if not followed by trailing surrogate
    )                    # end group
    |                    #  OR
    (                    # begin group
    (?<![\ud800-\udbff]) #   if not preceded by leading surrogate
    [\udc00-\udfff]      #   match trailing surrogate
    )                    # end group
    ''')

def invalid_unicode(s):
    assert isinstance(s, unicode)
    return lone.search(s) is not None
```

Answer (score 2):

To detect that the string is invalid `utf-8`, just wrap an attempt to encode it inside a `try/except` before executing it in `psycopg2`.

As for what caused the problem, there is a specific character in the middle of the string that is `utf-16` encoded: `\U000d8a85`. So it's not that Postgres does not consider it `utf-8`, it really isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but `x.encode('utf-8')` does not cause an exception. Neither does `x.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')`. Which leads me to believe either: python believes this to be valid utf-8, or python has fallbacks to decode utf-8 in a non-strict way.

Comment: Also, after further tinkering, it appears the specific character causing the problem is `\ud837` -- any idea what's going on there?